# I need help for the async/await method in .NET 8 and ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, redis

I have an asynchronous method that return Task in my API MVC project.

And this method has some code:

```
await _redis.StringSetAsync(
            $"manager:{userId}",
            chapterId,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(3), 
            flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Should I specify `ConfigureAwait(false)` in my project or not?

Is the code applied in another flow as I want to speed up the code, or in the main flow?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConfigureAwait impacts how await interacts with the sync-context, if one.

If this is modern ASP.NET, i.e. .NET 5 or later, or .NET Core App, then: there *is no sync context*, so: *it doesn't matter*. Feel free to omit it - it will behave identically with or without. If this is legacy .NET (.NET Framework), then things are more complicated.